# how to add extra information in the point/hoverover tooltip

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using [recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US) in my project. The chart that I'm using is `CustomizedLabelLineChart`. My problem is that the values that I'm using for X-axis are too long, so I need to kinda remove them from the X-axis but still have them in the chart-hoverover tooltip. How to do that? In other words, I need to have some extra data added to each point/hoverover tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom tooltip component and pass it as the prop called content in , here is an example with custom tooltip called

```
<CustomizedLabelLineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}>
  <XAxis dataKey="name" tick={<CustomAxisTick />} />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />}/>
  ...
</CustomizedLabelLineChart>
```

Reference: http://recharts.org/en-US/guide/customize